# Oracle SQL if statement based on parameter passed in via .sh script

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlparameter

I have a shell script which calls some SQL like so

```
sqlplus system/$password@$instance @./oracle/mysqlfile.sql $var1 $var2 $var3
```

Then in mysqlfile.sql, I define properties like this:

```
DEFINE var1=&1
DEFINE var2=&3
DEFINE var3=&3
```

Later in the file, I call another SQL script:

```
// i wish to wrap this in a if statement - pseudo-code
if(var3="true") do the following
@./oracle/myOthersqlfile.sql &&varA &&varB
```

I am not sure how to implement this though, any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could (ab)use substitution variables:

```
set termout off
column var3_path new_value var3_path
select case
  when '&var3' = 'true' then './oracle/myOthersqlfile.sql &&varA &&varB'
  else '/dev/null'
  end as var3_path
from dual;
set termout on

@&var3_path
```

The query between the `set termout` commands - which just hide the output of the query - uses a case expression to pick either your real file path or a dummy file; I've used /dev/null, but you could have a 'no-op' file of your own that does nothing if that's clearer. The query gives the result of that the alias `var3_path`. The `new_value` line before it turns that into a substitution variable. The `@` then expands that variable.

So if `var3` is 'true' then that runs:

```
@./oracle/myOthersqlfile.sql &&varA &&varB
```

(or, actually, with the `varA` and `varB` variables already replaced with their actual values) and if it is false it runs:

```
@/dev/null
```

which does nothing, silently.

You can `set verify on` around that code to see when and where substitution is happening.

Comment: good trick ;)  I  never used like this, I always apply the logic outsitde of sqlplus, but your example is quite good. Upvote is the less I can do

Answer (score 0):

You can't implement procedural logic into sqlplus. You have these options :

- Implement the IF-THEN-ELSE logic inside the shell script that is running the sqlplus.
- Use PL/SQL, but then your SQL Script should be called as a process inside an anonymous block, not like an external script.

In your case the easiest way is to change your shell script.

```
#/bin/bash
#
# load environment Oracle variables
sqlplus system/$password@$instance @./oracle/mysqlfile.sql $var1 $var2 $var3
# if then
if [ $var3 == "true" ]
then 
   sqlplus system/$password@$instance @./oracle/myOthersqlfile.sql 
fi
```

You should realise that sqlplus is just a CLI ( Command Line Interface ). So you can't apply procedural logic to it.

I have no idea what you do in those sql scripts ( running DMLs, creating files, etc ), but the best approach would be to convert them to PL/SQL, then you can apply whatever logic you need to.